# Magento2 category page first time taking time to open

Tags: magento2, optimization

Magento2 category page first time taking time to open & then the varnish from server is applied. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you check which things take time to load first time?

Comment: That's the issue I am not able to get that. Can you please guide me how to?

Comment: Check the console or try to check the page into speed testing tool like gtmatrix or google page speed.